# check software installed or not, if not then install using c#

Tags: c#, wpf, regedit

I've finished my C# WPF application, but I have a little problem :

My WPF application must need Adobe flash and .net framework and few softwares to run properly.
so this application have to install these softwares one by one automatically if not installed in client system instead of install by user self.

i have idea about check using "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" but dont know how to complete?

```
string uninstallKey = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";
            RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(uninstallKey);
            {
                foreach (string skName in rk.GetSubKeyNames())
                {
                    RegistryKey sk = rk.OpenSubKey(skName);
                    {
                        if (sk.GetValue("DisplayName") == "Adobe Flash Player ActiveX")
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Installed");

                           // how to run the software one by one here???????

                        }

                    }
                }
            }
```

any solution???

Note : i am giving this application to user in pen drive so i placed all needed software setup in pen drive itself.

Comment: Do you have an installer for your application?

Comment: Maybe check here first, this is not C# question at all but how to deploy applications http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software

Comment: @mikez yes actually i am giving this application in pen drive to user so i placed all the software installer in pen drive.

Comment: @Brandin i have all setup in pen drive so what i want to do is when i open my application automactically install adobe flash in client system from the pen drive, if not there.

Comment: What installer are you using

Comment: @Brandin .msi installer

Comment: Ok and how are you building your installer at the moment? Maybe you can edit the question to give details, i dont know the answer by the way but i think you need more info

Comment: @Brandin check my question now

Answer (score 1):

Creating your own installer for an application is a time consuming and error prone process which doesn't make sense to deal with, considering the multitude of installers that already exist.

My personal recommendation would be to examine the [Windows Installer XML Toolkit](http://wixtoolset.org/) (WiX).  It is completely free, and allows you to build a completely customized installer/uninstaller with external packages, with integration directly in Visual Studio.

Trying to do this by hand is not as simple as detecting a registry key; you must deal with out of date versions, file permissions, installation options, the possibility that the program may not exist on the system even though the registry key exists (just to name a few hurdles).  WiX will manage your program version and external dependencies by using the power of the Windows Installer Database Engine.

Comment: thanks for reply but i need to do this same by coding

Comment: the WiX toolkit IS coding, it's a project you add to your solution and then write XML to instruct the engine on your installation requirements.  Why re-invent the wheel and spend time troubleshooting bugs in a process that has already been perfected by others who know the internals of the installer database?

Answer (score 0):

It's to late but got the answer and your question is also very helpfull to me so thank you :)

```
var keyName = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Silverlight";
            using (var regKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(keyName))
            {
                var version = regKey.GetValue("Version");
                if (version + "" == "5.1.30514.0")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Installed");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Uninstalled");
                }
                var DisplayName = regKey.GetValue("DisplayName");
                lsitBox1.Items.Add(version);
                // lsitBox1.Items.Add(DisplayName);
            }
```